# How to get the end of a directory string

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

Purpose is to move files in their specified folders, from which they were in IF the date is at least a day old from today. I'm having some trouble finding functionality theoretically *FirstIndexOf* similarly to *LastIndexOf* I'd like to substring the beginning of a filepath in Dim filename, to get the name of the file and parse it to a date type. I don't want to remove 35 characters for dynamic reasons, but I'm not sure of what else to do. **VS2005 .NET 2.0**

```
Sub CopytoArchive(ByVal mydirpath As String)
    'Dim mydirpath As String = "C:\UTResults\"
    'C:\UTResults\Press3\sv70206655\data07012015.txt is an example of txtFileList
    '12345678901234567890123456789012345
    Dim txtFileList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(mydirpath, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 'Search all files in the given path with .txt type

    For Each txtName As String In txtFileList 'C:\UTResults\Press3\sv70206655\data07012015.txt 'is an example of txtFileList
        Dim pressname As String = txtName.Substring(0, txtName.LastIndexOf("\")) 'C:\UTResults\Press3\sv70206655 'take out the file extension
        pressname = pressname.Substring(0, pressname.LastIndexOf("\")) 'C:\UTResults\Press3 'take out the folder after the press folder 
        pressname = pressname.Remove(0, 13) 'Press3 'for a clean "PRESS" look

        Dim folderexists As String = "C:\writetest\" + pressname

        Dim filename = txtName.Substring(txtName.LastIndexOf("."))
        filename = filename.Remove(0, 35)

        Dim datestring = DateTime.ParseExact(filename, "MMddyyyy", Nothing)

        If datestring < Now.AddDays(-1) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(folderexists)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(txtName, folderexists + "\" + "data" + filename + ".txt")
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `System.IO.Path` has some great functions to manipulate filepath names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim filename = Path.GetFileName(txtName)
```